# why charles not capturing traffic when I set proxy in browser

Tags: http, fiddler, charles-proxy

I have to capture http request from charles. I am able to get normally. One site that is not working in my ip address, so I am using proxy I set proxy in my mozila browser. After setting proxy in browser charles is not capturing site calls.

What I have to do to make it happen , As well I tried in fiddler as well. Please help me to sort out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For fiddler you can download certmaker as you need a certificate in most cases for secure traffic:
http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid